# AWS RDS everyday reset my RDS password issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using AWS MySQL RDS for my application. Last few days every day my RDS password is reset. Every day, I need to reset master password for my RDS. Is there any solution?

Comment: The same is happening with me. did you find any solution?

Comment: This is also happening to me

Comment: For the resolution you will required to raise ticket to AWS support team, He will be able to provide the logs regarding the password change.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a non-master user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon RDS will not automatically reset your password. Either somebody is changing it, or you have an automated process that is changing it.

If it is the Master password that is changing, you should be able to find a `ModifyDbInstance` call in your **AWS CloudTrail** log. It will show the credentials that were used to issue the modify command.

Comment: my RDS password is auto reset everyday. Nobody change it, I also didn't create any process do it.

Comment: I didn't have CloudTrail enabled so there is nothing there. I have enabled it and will check tomorrow if this happens again

Comment: For the resolution you will required to raise ticket to AWS support team, He will be able to provide the logs regarding the password change. Sometime `AWS CloudTrail` not provide the password logs.

Answer (score 2):

In my case that was a Secrets Manager who automatically rotated RDS instance master password.

Completely forgot about that and panicked a bit when notification about password reset that I didn't issue showed up.

[image]

Comment: And also, if this is the case, then you're supposed to retrieve the secret from secret manager every time you connect or each time you receive a bad password error (but remember to limit number of retries).

Comment: Also there is an option to set up RDS event notifications and get a email every time password changes -- in a "Event subscriptions" section. Just to actualize all the passwords